# how to make a design pattern for popup

Tags: javascript

I would like to develop a popup function (html,css,js) and use it anywhere in the webpage.

Here is the pop function:

```
function pop (options) {
  var mod = function( options ) {
    var that = this;
    this.op = { title: 'new pop' }; // for startup

    for( var option in options ){
      this.op[ option ] = options[ option ];
    };

    this.title = options.title;
    this.build();

    this.remove = function() { // remove this pop
      document.body.removeChild( that.cover );
    };
  };

  mod.prototype.build = function() { // create new pop
    this.cover = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild( this.cover );
  };

  return new mod( options );
}; // pop

var callpop = pop( { title: 'make a pop' } ); // so i can call
callpop.remove(); // and remove it
```

First question, is this design pattern make sense?

Second question, can i do :

```
    this.remove = function() { // remove this pop
      document.body.removeChild( that.cover );
      that = undefined; // add this line to make the callpop undefined
    };
    console.log( callpop ); // so i can check if pop is display, than i can remove it by callpop.remove(), and make a new one callpop = pop()
```

beside give me a link, can u give me some short example please? Many thank!

**Update 1:**

I just would like to know, if you get a job to write a popups function, how would you code it? is my example make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are driving the whole popup flow with `javascript` thus it would be hard to make modifications on markup side. It's better to keep `html` in either `markup` or `templates`. Because it's easier to make edits in `markup` for the display part.

One very nice example of this would be how `bootstrap` manages its modal popups. Have a look at [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#modal-components). They drive it completely by markup and events are attached at the time of page load.

You can customize this behavior as per your needs but try to keep `javascript` in `.js` and `html` in `.html` or `.templates`.

Also, have a look at their source code for [modal](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/65ffb1c3b6e94440812a2e228cb8e8be512652ec/js/src/modal.js).

And for using template for modal you should have look at how [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/0d79005f8d1f4d674bb04ba93c41bb9c06280b4f/src/modal/modal.js) handles those scenarios.

---

## Update:

For a basic reference see this [demo](https://jsbin.com/yabedeh) in jsbin. And code [here](https://jsbin.com/yabedeh/edit?html,css,js).

Comment: I can understand what u mean about the display part, but i never play with bootstrap & angular, so really don't understand how can i use their code in my code. if you can provide some short example would be better.

Comment: @user3769916 Added link to demo and code. Have a look.

Comment: build an empty div inside body is a good idea to prevent any side effect created by appending popups html tag, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"> 
 function popup(mylink, windowname)
 { 
   if (!window.focus)
   return true; 
   var href; 
   if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') 
   href=mylink; 
   else href=mylink.href;
   window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes'); 
   return false; 
 }
 </SCRIPT>

popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi you can use this popup. Below the complete example of custom design
>   popup.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
    loadPopupBox();

    $('#popupBoxClose').click(function() {
      unloadPopupBox();
    });

    $('#container').click(function() {
      unloadPopupBox();
    });
  });

  function unloadPopupBox() {
    // TO Unload the Popupbox
    $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
    $("#container").css({
      // this is just for style  
      "opacity": "1"
    });
  }

  function loadPopupBox() {
    // To Load the Popupbox
    $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
    $("#container").css({
      // this is just for style
      "opacity": "0.3"
    });
    return false;
  }
```

```css
/* popup_box DIV-Styles*/

#popup_box {
  display: none;
  /* Hide the DIV */
  position: fixed;
  _position: absolute;
  /* hack for internet explorer 6 */
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 100;
  /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
  margin-left: 15px;
  /* additional features, can be omitted */
  border: 2px solid #ff0000;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
}

#container {
  background: #d2d2d2;
  /*Sample*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* This is for the positioning of the Close Link */

#popupBoxClose {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 15px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #6fa5e2;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <!-- HTML Structure for popup box-->
    <div id="popup_box">
      <!-- OUR PopupBox DIV-->
      <h1>This IS A Cool PopUp</h1>
      <div runat="server" id="dvContent"></div>
      <a id="popupBoxClose">Close</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Main Page -->
    <div id="container">      
      <h1>Click on link to load sample popup</h1>
      <input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btnClick" onclick="loadPopupBox();" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Sry guys but this is not what im looking for.